# Authorization http header is not working at Zend Soap Client

Tags: zend-framework, soap

I Used the below code to retrive the categories from the third party site using API, but unfortunately stream context is not able to requested at their API and resulting in the Internal Error.

FYI : It is used under zend framework.

```
$header = "Authorization: Bearer ".$accestoken."\r\n"."Content-Type:text/xml";//.'Content-Type:application/xml';

$wsdl = 'wsdl url';

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => $header,'method'=>'GET')));

             $options = array('stream_context'=>$context,'encoding'=>'ISO-8859-1','exceptions'=>FALSE);


            $params = array ('accessToken' => $accestoken);


            $response = $client->getAdCategories($params);

             print_r($response);
```

So please find the above code and provide some solution for this issue.

Comment: Describe the API?  Why does HTTP not work?  Is it a SOAP service, expecting a POST?  What specifically prevents authenticating with a HTTP GET request?

Answer (score 1):

```
$httpHeaders = array(
            'http'=>array(
            'protocol_version' => 1.1,
            'header' => "Authorization:Bearer ".$accestoken."\r\n" ,
                    "Connection: close"
            ));


$context = stream_context_create($httpHeaders);

    $soapparams = array(                    
                                            'stream_context' => $context,

                            );
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $soapparams);
$response = $client->getAdCategories($params);

         print_r($response);
```

Please refer https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49853

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see in the title at least this is a SOAP service you are trying to work with.  You should then be using something like the  [`Zend_Soap_Client`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.soap.client.html).

Looks like you have a WSDL... so,

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client("yourwsdl.wsdl");
```

and then make a request like

```
$retval = $client->method1(10);
```

Looking at your code I am not 100% sure what authentication approach is in use.  If basic HTTP auth you can just pass username and password as options in the client's constructor.

Setting a header might look something like this:

```
$auth = new stdClass();
$auth->user = 'joe';
$auth->token = '12345'; 

$authHeader = new SoapHeader('authNamespace', 'authenticate', $auth);

$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($authHeader));
```

If you need more help post your WSDL.

Comment: thanks for the response.....Actually what my problem is stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => $header,'method'=>'GET')));  ...... This header information is not passing at the request header ..... When this request header is created then the response will be fine..... So any PHP version with this stream_context_create function?

Comment: Well, 5.3.0 Added the optional params argument.  So using the second argument as you are requires 5.3.0 > otherwise the method is available since version 4.